# Is there any method to quantify parameter estimation uncertainty of method of moments fitting technique?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, maximum-likelihood, inference, method-of-moments

If I want to fit a distribution (let's say we can be certain about the type) to observations using maximum-likelihood method, I have many options to express the parameter estimation uncertainty due to scarcity of data, e.g. constructing confidence intervals using (following [Coles, 2001]):

- asymptotic normality [Coles, 2001, Ch. 2.6.4]
- deviance function [Coles, 2001, Ch. 2.6.5]
- profile likelihood [Coles, 2001, Ch. 2.6.6]

According to Coles all of these approaches are applicable <s>only</s> to maximum-likelihood estimation.

So my question: Is there any method to do similar quantification of parameter estimation uncertainty using method of moments?

Is it possible to derive asymptotic distributions as in case of maximum-likelihood approach?

I think bootstrapping might be used for this purpose, but it is a quite expensive approach. Any advice, reference is greatly appreciated.

---

S. Coles. 2001. [An Introduction to Statistical Modeling of Extreme Values](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-1-85233-459-8). Springer. ISBN 978-1-4471-3675-0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to Coles all of these approaches are applicable only to
>   maximum-likelihood estimation.

This is simply not true. GMM estimators are [asymptotically normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_method_of_moments#Asymptotic_normality). Deviance has a direct comparison in [tests based on the $J$ statistic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90525/how-to-do-model-testing-in-indirect-inference-simulated-general-method-of-moment/108327#108327). I am not aware of an equivalent to profile likelihoods, but Imbens and Spady [appear to construct something similar](http://scholar.harvard.edu/imbens/files/confidence_intervals_in_generalized_method_of_moments_models.pdf) with GMM by using empirical likelihoods.

A good reference for the asymptotic behavior of GMM estimators and their comparison to ML would be "Large Sample Estimation and Hypothesis Testing" by Newey and McFadden, which is available [here](http://www.econ.brown.edu/fac/Frank_Kleibergen/ec266/chap36neweymacfadden.pdf).

Comment: My bad, I think I added the word 'only', it is not in the book explicitly and I was referring to those particular chapters in the book with the formulas presented there and not to the approaches/methods in general. Thank you for the answer, references.